# Fetch data from asp.net into highchart

Tags: asp.net, angular, highcharts

I'm trying to make an application with highchart and asp.net and I followed several tutorials and applications because it's a new thing for me.
But I don't know how to fetch data from asp.net into highcharts.js. I tried to do a getChartData function  following  one video and then  I realised that is for chart.js.Can you give me  a idea?
This is my code:

bar-chart.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { SalesDataService } from '../../services/sales-data.service';
import * as moment from 'moment';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.css']
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _salesDataServices:SalesDataService ){}

  orders:any;
  orderLabels:string[];
  orderData:number[];
  public barChartLabels:string[];
  public barChartData:any[];

  title = 'myHighChartsApp';
  highcharts = Highcharts;
  public options: any ={
  chart : {
    type: "column"
    },
    title: {
    text: "Monthly Sales Chart Department Wise"
    },

    xAxis:{
    },
    yAxis: {
    title:{
    text:"Sales in Million $"
    }
    },
    series: []
    }
   
  

  ngOnInit() {
  

  }
 
getChartData(res:Response){

  this.orders=res['page']['data'];
 
  const data=this.orders.map(o =>o.total);
 
  const formattedOrders=this.orders.reduce((r,e) => {
   
    r.push([moment(e.placed).format('YY-MM-DD'),e.total]);
    return r;
  },[]);
  const p=[];

  console.log('formattedOrders:',formattedOrders);
  const chartData=formattedOrders.reduce((r,e)=>{
    const key=e[0];
if(!p[key]){
  p[key]=e;
  r.push(p[key]);
}else {
  
  p[key][1]+=e[1];
  
}
return r;
  },[]);
return chartData;
}
}
```

sales-data-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Order } from '../shared/order';

@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class SalesDataService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  
  getOrders( pageIndex: number, pageSize: number
    ) {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:5103/api/order/'+ pageIndex + '/' + pageSize
    )
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
  
  
     }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch data from asp.net into highchart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63129060/fetch-data-from-asp-net-into-highchart-js)

Comment: No,this is my first time when i try to use highchart.js and i don't understand how to fetch data .

Comment: The question is the same, so please do not duplicate threads.